# hCaptcha with Nodejs and React not working (csp)

Tags: node.js, content-security-policy, helmet.js, hcaptcha

I have nodejs with helmet as backend and react with the "@hcaptcha/react-hcaptcha" library in the frontend

nodejs:

```js
app.use(helmet());
app.use(helmet.contentSecurityPolicy({
    directives: {
        ...helmet.contentSecurityPolicy.getDefaultDirectives(),
        "script-src": [
            "'self'",
            "https://*.hcaptcha.com"
        ],
        "frame-src": [
            "'self'",
            "https://*.hcaptcha.com"
        ],
        "style-src": [
            "'self'",
            "https://*.hcaptcha.com",
            "'unsafe-inline'"
        ],
        "connect-src": [
            "'self'",
            "https://*.hcaptcha.com"
        ],
    },
}));
```

react:

```js
import HCaptcha from "@hcaptcha/react-hcaptcha";

export default function Captcha({ onVerify }) {
  return (
    <HCaptcha
      sitekey="10000000-ffff-ffff-ffff-000000000001"
      theme="dark"
      onVerify={onVerify}
    />
  );
}
```

However, the captcha is not displayed

I get this warning in chrome `VM15:161 crbug/1173575, non-JS module files deprecated.`

And firefox `This error page has no error code in its security info`

[screenshot of actual captcha](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DLMkl.png)

Comment: Helmet maintainer here. I don't know why this is happening, but it looks like HCaptcha might be trying to import a non-JS module, which causes issues. Could be worth looking up "crbug/1173575".

Comment: Hi, I have already done that without success.
Without helmet (csp) hCaptcha loads, only with csp the error appears.
Unfortunately I have not found a solution for this

Comment: Helmet is made up of several smaller modules and it's possible that one of them is causing the issue. Try [doing something similar to what I suggested in this comment](https://github.com/helmetjs/helmet/issues/401#issuecomment-1450211290) to see if that will fix things for you.

Answer (score 0):

I've tried to replicate your error, the only way was by loading localhost with port 3001 instead of 3000 (node vs react port) I used a 1:1 copy of your code and it produces a test captcha as expected:

[image: port 3000]

And when you try a different port, or don't specify one, the error occurs:

[image: using port 3001]